# Set pixel of image

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm having trouble trying to draw an image in AX. I don't know what's wrong, but this is what I'm doing as for

```
int x;
int y;
int colour = WinAPI::RGB2int(0, 255, 0);

for(y = 0; y < 10; y++){
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        img.setPixel(x, y, colour);
    }
}
```

I've instantiated a `new Image()`, which I'm trying to draw on, but the result is the same, no matter what I try to draw, a black image.

Answer (score 0):

With just this extract, it's complicated to guide you. If you want to see how to draw directly in a 'Window' control, you might look at 'tutorial_Tetris' form.